# Align the TextBox in middle of page on keypress event

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to align a textbox at the centre of the page on keypress event of textbox but i can only enlarge the size of the textbox with my code given below...

```
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function resize(selectObj) {

        selectObj.style.height = '400px';

        selectObj.style.width = '800px';

        selectObj.style.padding = '10px 10px 10px 10px';

        selectObj.style.position = 'absolute';

    }
</script>
```

```
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"  onkeypress="resize(this);">
</asp:TextBox>

    </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You would need to set margin-left and margin-right properties to center it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Will Help you definitely

```
$( "#txt" ).keypress(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'absolute', 
        'left': ($(window).width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2) + 'px',
        'top': ($(window).height() / 2 - $(this).height() / 2) + 'px',
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
$( "#txt" ).keypress(function() {
$("#maindiv").css({'display' : 'block', 'text-align' : 'center'});
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwncx/1/)

Update For Center of Screen

```
$( "#txt" ).keypress(function() {
$(this).css('margin-left', ($(window).width() / 2));
});
```

[Demo Fiddle Center of screen](http://jsfiddle.net/pwncx/11/)

Comment: I don't see OP has tagged question with JQuery

Comment: @Satpal will change it to javascript

Comment: it works fine but i want the text box to come at center on keypress

Comment: @RohitSingh center of screen or form or what

Comment: center of the screen @Rex

Comment: @RohitSingh check the center of screen fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can center it using absolute positioning. You should consider the width and height of the text box:

```
$( "#txt" ).keypress(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'absolute', 
        'left': ($(window).width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2) + 'px',
        'top': ($(window).height() / 2 - $(this).height() / 2) + 'px',
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#txt" ).keypress(function() {
$(this).css({
    'position': 'absolute', 
    'left': ($(window).width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2) + 'px',
    'top': ($(window).height() / 2 - $(this).height() / 2) + 'px',
});
```